# Null pointer exception when ran out of netbeans when getting image

Tags: java, netbeans

Getting a null pointer exception in the "animate" method. Unsure why as it works when frog goes up in my game. But when left right or down is pressed, it goes wrong. All the image files are in an "images" package. It works fine in netbeans. Any help is much appreciated. All paths have been checked thoroughly. I'll show all code as I cannot find the reason.

```
package frogger;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Frog extends Sprite implements Commons {

String frog = "/images/upFrogStill.png";
private int dx,dy;
private long timeLastChg;
private boolean leftReleased = true;
private boolean rightReleased = true;
private boolean upReleased = true;
private boolean downReleased = true;
private String audioFile = "/audio/hop.wav";
private Clip clip;
private boolean frogReset;

public Frog() {
    ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(frog));
    image = ii.getImage();
    width = image.getWidth(null);
    height = image.getHeight(null);
    resetState();
}
public void move() {
    x += dx;
    y += dy;
    animate();
}
public void animate() {
        ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(frog));
        image = ii.getImage();
}
public void muted() {
    if (Board.soundOn) {
        getSound();
        playSound();
    }
    if (!Board.soundOn) {
        if (clip != null) {
            stopSound();
        }
    }
}
private void getSound() {
    BufferedInputStream inaudio = new BufferedInputStream(getClass().getResourceAsStream(audioFile));
    clip = null;
    try {
        clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(inaudio));
    } catch (LineUnavailableException | UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
}
public void playSound() {
    clip.start();
}
public void stopSound() {
    clip.stop();
}
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int key = e.getKeyCode();
    if (frog != null) {
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timeLastChg > 250) {
            if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
                frog = "/images/leftFrogJump.png";
                frogReset = false;
                getSound();
                playSound();
                muted();
                if (rightReleased && upReleased && downReleased) {
                    x -= 15;
                    if (x < -5) {
                        x += 15;
                    }
                }
                leftReleased = false;
                animate();
            }
            if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                frog = "/images/upFrogJump.png";
                frogReset = false;
                getSound();
                playSound();
                muted();
                if (leftReleased && rightReleased && downReleased) {
                    y -= 15;
                }
                upReleased = false;
                animate();
            }
            if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
                frog = "/images/downFrogJump.png";
                frogReset = false;
                getSound();
                playSound();
                muted();
                if (leftReleased && rightReleased && upReleased) {
                    y += 15;
                    if (y > 410) {
                        y -= 15;
                    }
                }
                downReleased = false;
                animate();
            }
            if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
                frog = "/images/rightFrogJump.png";
                frogReset = false;
                getSound();
                playSound();
                muted();
                if (leftReleased && upReleased && downReleased) {
                    x += 15;
                    if (x > 390) {
                        x -= 15;
                    }
                }
                rightReleased = false;
                animate();
            }
            timeLastChg = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
    }
}
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    int key = e.getKeyCode();
    if (frog != null) {
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            frog = "/images/leftFrogStill.png";
            if (!leftReleased && !frogReset) {
                x -= 15;
                if (x < 0) {
                    x += 15;
                }
            }
            leftReleased = true;
            animate();
        }
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT && !frogReset) {
            frog = "/images/rightFrogStill.png";
            if (!rightReleased) {
                x += 15;
            }
            if (x > 390) {
                x -= 15;
            }
            rightReleased = true;
            animate();
        }
        //Up released
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP && !frogReset) {
            frog = "/images/upFrogStill.png";
            if (!upReleased) {
                y -= 15;
            }
            upReleased = true;
            Board.scoreInt += 10;
            animate();
        }
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN && !frogReset) {
            frog = "/images/downFrogStill.png";
            if (!downReleased) {
                y += 15;
                if (y < 410) {
                    Board.scoreInt -= 10;
                }
                if (y > 410) {
                    y -= 15;
                }
            }
            downReleased = true;
            animate();
        }
    }
}
final void resetState() {
    frogReset = true;
    frog = "/images/upFrogStill.png";
    x = 185;
    y = 397;
}
}
```

Comment: Does this path `/images/upFrogStill.png` exist if you start looking from the root of your application classpath? Or `/audio/hop.wav`?

Comment: Yeah it does. It loads at the start. It's  when I press left or right or down, it say's null pointer exception in the animate method.

Comment: Can you please show the complete stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that all images are present in the right directories/folders.  Introduce debug output with the full paths being expected by the program.  Something like

```
System.err.println( new File("yourFileName").getAbsolutePath() );
```

Comment: The files are resources in the `jar`/classpath. You wouldn't use `File` for that.

Comment: File actually worked fine in the jar. Used this and found the error. Checked it so many times and still didn't notice it. One of the images had one letter lowercase instead of upper. Why is it that in netbeans it's not case sensitive but outside in a jar file it is case sensitive?

Answer (score 0):

I refuse to believe that all of the following paths exists as a resource correctly:

```
frog = "/images/leftFrogJump.png";
frog = "/images/upFrogJump.png";
frog = "/images/downFrogJump.png";
frog = "/images/rightFrogJump.png";
frog = "/images/leftFrogStill.png";
frog = "/images/rightFrogStill.png";
frog = "/images/upFrogStill.png";
frog = "/images/downFrogStill.png";
```

You will have to show a screenshot of your resource directory for me to believe that all those files really exists.

Comment: It was a lowercase character issue. Derp.

Comment: Told you :) Please mark answer as accepted. (You should also do that on several of your old questions)